# ESP8266-RTOS-SDK - cannot connect to WPA2 network depending on esp_wifi_init() location

Tags: c, esp8266, freertos, esp8266wifi

I encounter a strange issue while working on my project with ESP8266 and using FreeRTOS SDK (version *release/v3.4*).

In my code, I'd like to have 5 functions for controlling WiFi state:

- wifi_initialize()
- wifi_station_connect()
- wifi_station_disconnect()
- wifi_ap_start()
- wifi_ap_stop()

I believe the names are self-descriptive. The (simplified) code for first 2 (only ones relevant to the problem) is as follows:

```
void wifi_initialize()
{
    tcpip_adapter_init();

    esp_event_handler_register(WIFI_EVENT, ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, &event_handler, NULL);
    esp_event_handler_register(IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP, &event_handler, NULL);

    wifi_init_config_t init_cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT(); // Problematic when called here
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&init_cfg));                // Problematic when called here
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_APSTA));      // Problematic when called here
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start());                        // Problematic when called here
}

void wifi_station_connect()
{
    // wifi_init_config_t init_cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT(); // OK when called here
    // ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&init_cfg));                // OK when called here
    // ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_APSTA));      // OK when called here
    // ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start());                        // OK when called here

    wifi_config_t wifi_config;
    if (xSemaphoreTake(common_settings_mutex, pdMS_TO_TICKS(20)))
    {
        memcpy(wifi_config.sta.ssid, common_settings.wifi_ssid, 32);
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Using SSID: %s", wifi_config.sta.ssid);
        memcpy(wifi_config.sta.password, common_settings.wifi_password, 64);
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Using password: %s", wifi_config.sta.password);
        xSemaphoreGive(common_settings_mutex);
    }
    if (strlen((char*) wifi_config.sta.password))
    {
        wifi_config.sta.threshold.authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK;
    }

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &wifi_config));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_connect());
}
```

The problem: with the code as above, the ESP is unable to connect to password-protected networks. The SSID and password copied to `wifi_config` are correct as checked using logging. Connecting to open networks (using empty password) works fine.
The bizzare part: moving call to `esp_wifi_init()` from `wifi_initialize()` to `wifi_station_connect()` solves the problem, even though in any case `wifi_station_connect()` is called directly after `wifi_initialize()` (`esp_wifi_set_mode()` and `esp_wifi_start()` are also moved, since they need to be called after `esp_wifi_init()`).

I will be grateful for any suggestions what might be wrong here, or how to debug this issue/

Comment: Maybe it's some kind of timing issue? Try adding a couple of  `__asm__ __volatile__ ("nop");` after `esp_event_handler_register` and see what happens.

Comment: race condition with automatic reconnection to last used WiFi network?

Comment: @HubertBossy Thanks for suggestion, unfortunately adding 10 of them didn't help. Earlier I have also tried having init before handler registration, to no avail.

Comment: @Juraj I'm not sure how that would work? But I'm connecting to the same network all the time, and just moving init between those functions changes behavior.

Comment: the esp8266 SDK stores the network name and password in flash and at start it connects to this network. while it already started connecting and you do it too in your program it conflicts.

Comment: Hm, I see, but wouldn't that occur independent of init() location? Also, how could I mitigate this behavior - is there a way to force SDK to not store this info in FLASH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question since I found a solution: the `wifi_config_t` union/struct must be defined before values are assigned to SSID and password fields. This line:

```
wifi_config_t wifi_config;
```

Has to become:

```
wifi_config_t wifi_config = {};
```

Then everything works as expected.

EDIT
The reason for this behavior is lack of memory allocation for an union before it is declared. In Espressif's examples the config is initialized during variable definition, so this problem doesn't occur. That said, it's interesting the in some cases the code was working fine, and that no exception was thrown.